# Neovim init.lua sourcing not working when trying to install Lazy.nvim

Tags: lua, neovim

I am new to Neovim s (and vim in general) so I might be missing something obvious. Anyway, I am trying to follow a video to setup a Neovim to replace my IDE (VSCode). This video start with setting up the Lazy plugin manager.

I've got a super simple setup and I am only trying to install Lazy but my `init.lua` file is giving me `init.lua:1: number expected` whenever I try to source it.

Here's my `~/.config/nvim` directory:

```
╰─❯ tree
.
├── init.lua
└── lua
    ├── config
    │   └── init.lua
    ├── plugins
    └── util

5 directories, 2 files
```

Here is my `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`

```
require("config")
```

And here is my `~/.config/nvim/lua/config/init.lua`

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)


vim.g.mapleader = " " -- Make sure to set `mapleader` before lazy so your mappings are correct

-- Initialise Lazy by installing some basic plugins
require("lazy").setup({
  "folke/which-key.nvim",
  { "folke/neoconf.nvim", cmd = "Neoconf" },
  "folke/neodev.nvim",
})
```

What is incorrect with my setup? I can't figure it out and don't understand where I am going wrong. This looks just like the video I am watching and the author of that shows the Lazy plugin loaded and working.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your error but i'm not able to, could you provide your output of
`:echo stdpath('config')` inside neovim?

Comment: Result is `/Users/wmoorby/.config/nvim` so my nvim is pointing to the correct location to be picking up the config

Comment: are u still getting the `init.lua:1: number expected` error? I've been trying to reproduce it but I just can't seem to get it, it must be coming from somewhere

Comment: I looked at `:checkhealth` as well, no issues with config there, but it shows lazy.nvim` and states there are no issues, but the Lazy UI never appears, so it clearly isn't loading properly

Comment: Yup, when I source my `init.lua`.


╰─❯ source init.lua

init.lua:1: number expected

Comment: @TAEFED Whats the best way to completely wipe all nvim config + plugin data so I can start on a completely clean slate to see if that helps?

Comment: keep your config but go to /Users/wmoorby/.local/share/ and delete the nvim folder,
then restart your terminal, start nvim and it should load up lazyvim, you could also delete your lazy-lock.json for good measure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256045/discussion-between-taefed-and-mo0rby).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keep your config but go to `~/.local/share/` and delete the nvim folder, then restart your terminal, start nvim and it should load up lazyvim.

Answer (score 1):

As TAEFFED told me to do in the comments + chat, I deleted my `~/.local/share/nvim` directory. I then went and relaunched nvim and Lazy loaded just as expected. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar issue with neodev. It should work if you remove neodev from the config. Don't ask me why it's not working :D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35501558)